# Tornado: Application or HTTPServer

Tags: tornado

Various Tornado documents show using either tornado.web.Application directly:

```
application = tornado.web.Application(endpoints, **settings)
application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

or via HTTPServer:

```
application = tornado.web.Application(endpoints, **settings)
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

**What's the difference?** The documentation hasn't cleared it up to me.

Comment: As you can see in [source code](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#Application.listen) application.listen() starts HTTPServer under the hood. So the difference is first is implicit HTTPServer creation, second is explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Application.listen` is shorthand for constructing an `HTTPServer` and calling `listen` on it. This is convenient because you probably need to import the `Application` class anyway and won't otherwise need to touch the `HTTPServer`.

The only time you would need to construct an `HTTPServer` by hand is if you need to call some methods other than `listen` on it (you can even pass `HTTPServer` constructor arguments through `Application.listen`, so you can get HTTPS that way). You would need to do this if you're using multi-process mode, or using something unusual with `HTTPServer.add_sockets`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html):

> Typical applications have little direct interaction with the HTTPServer class except to start a server at the beginning of the process (and even that is often done indirectly via `tornado.web.Application.listen`).

Basically, `HTTPServer` is the built-in HTTP server implementation that Tornado uses by default to serve its application. You can also serve a Tornado app via a different web server (e.g. [via WSGI](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#running-tornado-apps-on-wsgi-servers)) if you had needs that another web server handled better.

Comment: Both blocks of code result in a server listening on the port, serving the endpoints. So is there ever a reason to explicitly invoke HTTPServer? Does it provide any additional functionality or control? Apparently I'll need HTTPServer if I want to set up HTTPS, but are there other things I'll only figure out when I run across them buried in the documentation for other features?